# MediaRecorder records audio in slow speed

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

if I use `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC` sound is recorded normally. If `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK` the sound is played in slow speed. I need it `VOICE_DOWNLINK`. how to fix it? I found a couple of tips :

```
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
```

and

```
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
```

but it did not help

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL) - 1, 0);
        audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
        myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK);
        myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        myAudioRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(96000);
```

Comment: AMR NB has a fixed sample rate of 8000 Hz, so it doesn't make much sense to specify any other sample rate when using that encoder.

Comment: i get it. but how do I write a record in the normal way? she slowed down

Comment: If you're going to use `AMR_NB` you should probably use `setAudioChannels(1);` and `setAudioSamplingRate(8000);`. If you still get messed up files it could be an issue with the device that you're using (i.e. that it doesn't fully support the voice call audio sources).

Comment: I do not in principle be used AMR_NB. me it is important to keep a record. Now I will try your advice. strange but I could not find this in the official documentation.

Comment: did not help. can really matter in my phone. I'll check on the other. but you can check it on the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on MediaRecorder few days ago and I faced the same problem .I solved it by choosing following options , you can try this code .This code is working fine for MotoE and Samsung Grand 2 .

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
            recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
            recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);`
```

Comment: did not help. probably a problem with the phone. I'll let you know as testing on the other.

Comment: Which device are you using right now and what problem are you getting with above code?